# In what cases would I set a parameter to use storage instead of memory?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

If I had understood correctly so far, by default, the parameters of a function are stored in the memory except for `external` functions which are stored in calldata which I assume is pretty much in the memory but just at a different location.

I have also seen examples where parameters are instructed to store in `storage` instead.

For eg: `function foo(uint[] storage _data, uint _value)`

Since the parameters of a function are just values that we use and don't really care about them once the function finishes, in what scenario would I want to store parameters in storage? Also, since `storage` is supposed to be persistent, is the value of the parameters somehow going to be available on the next call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### `calldata` vs `memory`

> If I had understood correctly so far, by default, the parameters of a function are stored in the memory except for `external` functions which are stored in calldata

This used to be true until Solidity 0.5.0, which is very old by now. In newer versions you have to explicitly specify where the parameter is stored.

> calldata which I assume is pretty much in the memory but just at a different location.

You could say that `calldata` is also in memory but it's not the memory belonging to contract. It does not have an address that you could use with the `MLOAD`/`MSTORE` opcodes to reach it. When the caller is another contract, calldata is mapped from the memory space of that contract and only it can reach it.

The most important feature of `calldata` is that it's read-only. It contains the parameters in the [ABI-encoded form](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_calldata.html). When you declare a parameter as `memory`, the compiler inserts extra code to decode the values from calldata and copy them to a new location in memory, which adds some extra cost so it's only necessary if you want to modify the value in place.

#### What a `storage` parameter actually is

> Since the parameters of a function are just values that we use and don't really care about them once the function finishes, in what scenario would I want to store parameters in storage?

A `storage` parameter does not really mean your data is copied into `storage`. All parameters are actually stored on the stack. Since stack in the EVM only has 16 slots accessible at any given moment, storing large amounts of data there is not viable. It works fine for values types like ints or addresses because they always fit in a 32-byte slot but for reference types like arrays or structs, which require more space or can grow, Solidity only puts a reference on the stack and the actual content is elsewhere. It can be in storage, memory or calldata and you need to specify that when you declare the parameter.

So a `storage` parameter is just a pointer/reference. Internally it's just a number that indicates the storage position at which the actual content can be found. Note that local variables declared as `storage` work the same way - they do not allocate a new area of storage. They can only point at existing storage variables declared at the contract level.

#### Possible uses for `storage` parameters

There are two main use cases for `storage` parameters:

1. **Giving libraries access to storage variables**. A library function can potentially could be called by many different contracts having different storage variables and, if it's an external call, these contracts are not known at compilation time. It cannot refer to their variables by their names. Solidity solves this problem by making it possible to pass a reference to a storage variable into a function via a parameter.
2. **Making your functions generic in regards to storage**. Say, your contract stores several instances of a struct and you want to have a function that validates them. You obviously do not want to have to write one function per instance and you can avoid it by having the function accept the struct as a parameter. But if you declare the parameter as `memory`, each call will involve allocating a new instance in memory and copying its data from storage which is costly. A better solution is to declare the parameter as `storage` so that your function can accept a reference to it, which is potentially much lighter.

Answer (score 9):

Cameel's answer is excellent, but to make it less theoretical and a little more concrete, here's a tldr:

- use calldata when you only need read-only data, avoiding the cost of allocating `memory` or `storage`.
- use `memory` if you want your parameter itself to be mutable.
- use `storage` if your argument passed in will already exist in `storage`, to prevent copying something into `storage` over into `memory` unnecessarily.

**So, to clarify, there are times where using `storage` is more efficient than using `memory`!**

To explain with some code:

```
contract str {
  uint[] x = [10];
  function useStore(uint[] storage y) internal view returns (uint) {
    return y[0];
  }
  function useMem(uint[] memory y) internal view returns (uint) {
    return y[0];
  }

  function efficient(uint n) external view returns (uint) {
    return useStore(x) + n;
  }
  function inefficient(uint n) external view returns (uint) {
    return useMem(x) + n;
  }  
}
```

As a user of this contract, you can call either `efficient()` or `inefficient()`. They should be functionally identical, but the only difference is that internally, one calls "useStore" and one calls "useMem".

Both of them are being passed `x`, which is an array that already exists in `storage`. When we call `useStore(x)`, *no new memory is allocated for argument `y`--it just uses the existing pointer in `storage`!* Meanwhile, `useMem(x)` has to copy `x` into `memory`.

`efficient()` saves about 400 gas in `0.8.10` over `inefficient()`.

Comment: Why is it that sometimes you don't need to call any of the variables at all? Like in your `efficient` and `inefficient` functions, why doesn't `n` need to have `calldata`? Also, when defining an argument that is in the shape of a struct, snould it be calldata or storage? So like `fn(MyStruct storage myStruct) {}` or `fn(MyStruct calldata myStruct) {}`

Comment: Great question. As per [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#reference-types), structs & arrays & mappings (so called "reference types") require this as an explicit declaration. In other cases, it is optional.