# Member "slice" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Ballot.Proposal storage ref[ ] storage ref

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, blockchain, remix

I'm new to solidity, I'm writing a smart contract for ballot process but getting the error in my `ballot` function in the line `proposals = proposals.slice(0, _numProposals);`. I've traversed all the relevant questions to it but finally concluded to ask you people when my problem seemed different from others.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract Ballot {

  struct Voter {
    uint weight;
    bool voted;
    uint8 vote; 
  }

  struct Proposal {
    uint voteCount; 
  }

  enum Stage {Init, Reg, Vote, Count}
  Stage public stage = Stage.Init;

  address chairperson;
  mapping(address => Voter) voters;
  Proposal[] proposals;

  uint startTime;

  /// Create a new ballot with $(_numProposals) different proposals.
  function ballot(uint8 _numProposals) public {
    chairperson = msg.sender;
    voters[chairperson].weight = 2;
    proposals = proposals.slice(0, _numProposals);
    stage = Stage.Reg;
    startTime = block.timestamp;
  }
```

I'm getting the same error after I've also added `proposals = proposals.slice[0 : _numProposals];`. Please explain to me in detail what is the root cause?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html?highlight=slice#array-slices)

> As of now, array slices are only implemented for calldata arrays.

Your proposals array is stored in the storage and it is not calldata. check these for more information about the difference between storage , memory, and calldata

- https://solidity-by-example.org/data-locations/
- [When should I use calldata and when should I use memory?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74442/when-should-i-use-calldata-and-when-should-i-use-memory)
- [In what cases would I set a parameter to use storage instead of memory?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107028/in-what-cases-would-i-set-a-parameter-to-use-storage-instead-of-memory)